# Having a job offer but in the initial take home task I got a friend to help a bit

Tags: job-offer

Though the company did not specify if I can ask for help. I passed later interviews without any further help and gained the missing knowledge of the initial test by now. I am pretty confident that if I take the initial test now I can do it without any help.

I want to accept the offer but feel a bit guilty as I have never done anything like that before. I also worried being found out, what to do now?

Comment: What does "help a bit" mean?  Did he give you advice, or did he sit there and write some code for you?

Comment: I asked for some advice from my friend who showed me an example which accounted for 25% of the task. I did not copy his answer of course but used my own words as  I know how to do it in principle but just lack of the details at the time. Now I have managed to gain that knowledge and am confident I don't need any help on it anymore.

Comment: Don't tell them. Telling them would be shooting yourself in the foot. Nothing good can come out of that. If another difficult problem comes up, you can always stall and ask your friends for help.

Answer (score 4):

### Working in a business isn't the same as schoolwork

I'm getting the impression that you're very new to the workforce.  If that's wrong, feel free to take this answer with a grain of salt.

Anyway, schoolwork and business development are *wildly* different animals.  Schoolwork is meant to be about personal improvement - when a professor assigns a project, they're not doing it because they actually plan on using your output - but because they want you to gain experience and knowledge.

Businesses are the exact opposite.  When they assign something, they usually couldn't care less whether you already knew how to do it, or had to learn something new to get the task done.  They generally care about A) does it work, and B) how long did it take to develop.

This isn't to say, "Let someone else do you application project" or such.  The company wants a good sense on whether you can do the job - not whether your *friend* can.  That said?  On the job, you're going to be asking for help *all the time* - whether that's a coworker or StackOverflow or Google.  **So asking someone else to know how to do something, learning how to do it, and the delivering a final product?  That's actually a *good* thing.**

Comment: Although anyone who has worked for more than a handful of years will agree with this, the **interviewing** process is still highly academic. Some of the take-home tests for development positions are absurdly huge in scope, and in general I get the sense that most companies have no idea how to hire for developers.

Comment: This advice is absolutely wrong.  When I give someone an interview assignment, it's meant to be a study in what they can do.  Because I'm not hiring their friend.  And in the workplace, their friend can't help without exposing them to company IP and secrets.  So no, you can't ask a friend.  Googling is a completely different (and accepted) method because you can do that on the job.

Comment: Also, I don't know where you went to school, but every math, physics, chem, EE, etc problem in school was done in groups working together to explain it to the people who didn't get it.  They were called study groups.  Most of my EE homework was so hard that most groups only had 1 person per question get it right, you had to work together.  Programming assignments weren't cowritten, but you definitely asked people for help on the hard parts-  ACM even had tutors in the labs (I was one).  So yeah, if anything you got that backwards.

Comment: @GabeSechan so if I ask a friend it is bad, but if I post it on Stack Overflow and they answer it is ok?

Comment: @GabeSechan - From the OP: "I asked for some advice from my friend who showed me an example which accounted for 25% of the task. I did not copy his answer of course but used my own words as I know how to do it in principle but just lack of the details at the time."  Even before that comment, I didn't get the sense that the OP had the friend do the work.  The asked the friend for help on knowing *how*, but still did the work.  So, no, this answer is not "absolutely wrong"

Comment: @Kevin So he got 25% of the answer from someone else?  Yeah, if I was feeling generous I'd give him another question, but on this one he'd be an absolute no hire.  That's completely unacceptable.  And I probably wouldn't do that-  he knows he was supposed to do his own work, I could never trust him to be honest after that.

Comment: @GabeSechan - Lol, the friend didn't submit that 25% - you're acting as if OP just submitted their friend's code.  If OP were asked to, say, put together a SOAP service, and didn't know/remember how to deploy to IIS to test it, there's no substantial difference between asking a friend how to do that and asking Google.  Again, the friend didn't submit their work; the friend didn't write the answer.

Comment: @Kevin He said he cribbed 25% of the answer from the friend.  And quite frankly, I don't believe they didn't submit the friends code.  Oh sorry, they just took the entire structure from it and retypes it themselves-  that's equivalent.  That is not acceptable.  Of course this is why I don't do take home assignments when I'm interviewing-  because people like you and the OP exist.  If I can't see them write it I don't trust it.

Answer (score 3):

You should not have done that, but it is not significant. It's done and over. Sign your offer, don't mention it ever again, and next time, clarify ahead of the policy of getting help— the company will probably say something like, "use the internet (and cite sources), don't ask other people, do your own work."

Comment: This is probably the right answer.  You shouldn't have done it, but the odds of ever being caught are 0-  nobody but you will ever think of your interview again.  The only way it can come back to bite you is if you're incapable of doing the job, in which case you'll be fired for performance.